# Locked-Down SFTP access to mounted WinServer sub-folder

Tags: server, sftp

If someone could lend some help with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated!  I have two servers at a site - one running WinServer 2012 and the other running Ubuntu Server 16.04.5.  The Ubuntu server currently has a network share from the WinServer mounted via CIFS.

What I want to do is create a user account on the Ubuntu server that will only have SFTP (not SSH) access to a specific sub-folder on the WinServer.  I used these instructions as a guide initially: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-18-04

Initially I didn't do anything under Step 2, and for Step 3 tried setting the ChrootDirectory to the already mounted WinServer location but with the sub-folder specified in the path (e.g. /media/<WIN_SERVER_NAME>/folder/sub-folder).  I then tried to SFTP in using FileZilla, and was able to connect using the new user ($user) I had created in Step 1, and see contents of the folder, but couldn't upload anything to it.

I then tried messing around with mounting the WinServer sub-folder but telling Ubuntu to mount it with 0757 file and directory permissions, or mount it with $user:$user ownership, but each time I did that and then tried to SFTP in I got fatal errors in FileZilla and couldn't connect.

I thought at this point let me see about asking for some help to see how I can accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.  Any inside or advice is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: FYI: If your system is only reporting itself as 16.04.5, you're very behind on upgrades (and hopefully off-line security wise).  A fully-updated *xenial* system reports itself as 16.04.7 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/ showing you haven't upgraded since early 2019 or before; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/)

Comment: Hmm...I have been performing updates pretty regularly so not sure why I'm not getting updated to 16.04.7 - is there some different way of upgrading to this point release?  Thx!

Comment: `sudo apt update` will update your software lists (lists of packages available), and then a simple `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (or `apt full-uprade`) will install all upgrades available `upgrade` only installs some having restrictions on what can be upgraded  (refer `apt` & `apt-get` man pages for details.. they differ a little in restrictions and I don't know which you use; `apt` is more complete in later releases too and I forget your software stack as no longer use *xenial*..)

Comment: Got it - thanks!